# Translate "there exists one" from English sentence to ALCQO description logic

Tags: description-logic

I have the following English question

*There exists one school student.*

And I would like to translate it to ALCQO or First order logic.

I have written the following:

```
∃SchoolStudent
```

or in First Order Logic:

```
∃x(SchoolStudent(x))
```

However, I know from mathematics and the theory that *∃* is translated as "at least one" or "some". Thus, I am wondering if the following two options are correct:

*approach 1*

```
¬∃x(SchoolStudent(x))
```

*approach 2*

```
(≥1student.SchoolStudent)⊓(≤1student.SchoolStudent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`∃SchoolStudent` is meaningless in ALCQO. The only constructor available in ALCQO using existential restrictions are of the form

∃r.C

which is interpreted as

{d ∈ Δ<sup>I</sup> | there is an e ∈ Δ<sup>I</sup> with (d, e) ∈ r<sup>I</sup> and e ∈ C<sup>I</sup>}

In first order logic ∃r.C translates to π<sub>x</sub>(∃r.C) = ∃y.r(x, y) ∧ π<sub>y</sub>(C).

To define a school with only 1 student you will have to have the concepts School and Student and a role which can be used to associate a student with a school, say `hasStudent`.

School ≡ ∃hasStudent.Student ⊓ ≤1hasStudent.Student

This means School here is the set of schools that have only a single student.

But we can also define School as anything that has more than 1 student and then define a specific individual of the school as a school with only 1 student.

School ≡ ∃hasStudent.Student

School(x)

≤1hasStudent.Student(x)